# Joint distribution using tail

Tags: probability-theory

Recently, I saw $P(X \ge x, Y < y)$ the following expression for the joint distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$.

I'm wondering, does this representation uniquely determine the representation of the joint distribution of  X and Y, and can I use it interchangeably with the more known definition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown directly by Kavi the answer is: "yes".

More generally we can state the following.

---

It is a well known theorem that probability measures that coincide on a $\pi$-system $\mathcal V$ (i.e. a non-empty collection closed under binary intersection) will also coincide on the $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by that system, i.e. on $\sigma(\mathcal V)$.

Further it can easily be shown that $\mathcal V:=\{[x,\infty)\times(-\infty,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb R\}$ is indeed a $\pi$-system and also that $\sigma(\mathcal V)$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$.

A direct consequence is that a probability distribution on $\mathbb R^2$ is completely determined by the values it takes on elements of $\mathcal V$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $P(X  \geq x,Y<y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ then you can get $P(Y<y)$ by letting $x \to -\infty$. And then you can write $P(X<x,Y<y)=P(Y<y)-P(X  \geq x,Y<y)$. This determines the joint distribution. Of course,  if you know the joint distribution the you can write down $P(X  \geq x,Y<y)$ , so you can use these two interchangeably.